# How to prove the equation holds in asymptotic sense

Tags: pr.probability

The random variables $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{k}$ have a **multinomial distribution** if and only if their joint probability mass distribution is given by
$$
\mathbf{P}\left\{X_{1}=n_{1}, X_{2}=n_{2}, \ldots, X_{k}=n_{k}\right\} 
=
\frac{n !}{n_{1} ! n_{2} ! \ldots n_{k} !} p_{1}^{n_{1}} p_{2}^{n_{2}} \ldots p_{k}^{n_{k}} $$
where $p_{i}\in \left (0,1 \right ),n_{i}\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\},\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_{i}=n \text { and } \sum_{i=1}^{k} p_{i}=1 .$

We say that

1. A sequence of random variables $\xi_{n}=O_{\mathrm{P}}(1) $ if and only if for any  $\epsilon>0$,there is $M>0$ such that $\mathbf{P}\left(\left|\xi_{n}\right| \ge M\right)<\epsilon, n\ge 1 $;
2. A sequence of random variables $\xi_{n}=o_{\mathbf{p}}\left( 1\right)$ if and only if  $\xi_{n} \stackrel{\mathbf{p}}{\longrightarrow} 0$ as  $n\rightarrow\infty.$

Show that \begin{equation}
\boxed{2\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\log\frac{n_i}{np_i} = \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(n_i-np_i)^2}{np_i} + o_{\mathbf{p}}(1)\quad (n\rightarrow \infty).}
\end{equation}

---

The following is my thoughts,but I'm not sure if it's correct. Please provide corrections if necessary.

By Bernoulli’s law of large numbers, For every  $\varepsilon>0$  we have

\begin{aligned}
&\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{P}\left(\left|\frac{n_{i}}{n}-p_{i}\right| \geq \varepsilon\right)=0,\quad\text{i.e.}\quad\frac{n_i-np_{i}}{np_{i}}=o_{\mathbf{p}}(1).
\end{aligned}

By CLT,The asymptotic distribution of $\frac{n_i-n p_i}{\sqrt{n}}$ is $\mathcal{N}\left( 0,p_{i}(1-p_i) \right )$,i.e.$\frac{n_i-n p_i}{\sqrt{n}}\stackrel{\mathbf{d}}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{N}\left( 0,p_{i}(1-p_i) \right ).$
Then $\frac{n_i-n p_i}{\sqrt{n}}=O_{\mathbf{p}}(1)\Leftrightarrow n_i-n p_i=O_{\mathbf{p}}(\sqrt{n}).$

\begin{aligned}
2\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\log\frac{n_i}{n p_i}
&=2\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\log\left(1+\frac{n_i-np_i}{n p_i}\right)\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\left[\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)-\frac12\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)^2+O\left(\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)^3\right)\right]\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\left[\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)-\frac12\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)^2\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_{i}O_{\mathbf{p}}\left((\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n})^3\right)\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\left[\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)-\frac12\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)^2\right]+O_{\mathbf{p}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(n_i-n p_i)^2}{n p_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(n_i-n p_i\right)\cdot O_{\mathbf{p}}\left(\left(\frac{n_i-n p_i}{n p_i}\right)^2\right)+O_{\mathbf{p}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(n_i-n p_i)^2}{n p_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(n_i-n p_i\right)\cdot O_{\mathbf{p}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+O_{\mathbf{p}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(n_i-n p_i)^2}{n p_i}+O_{\mathbf{p}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(n_i-n p_i)^2}{n p_i}+o_{\mathbf{p}}\left(1\right).
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

I will first remark that your condition 1, that $\xi_n = O_P(1)$, is exactly the definition that the family $(\xi_n)_n$ is tight.

Here is a shorter proof than your computation. Let us use $\ln(1+x) = x + x^2 \phi(x)$ with $\phi$ continuous and $\phi(x) \to -1/2$ for $x\to 0$:
\begin{align}
2\sum_i n_i \ln \frac{n_i}{n p_i} &= 2\sum_i n_i \frac{n_i - np_i}{n p_i} + 2\sum_i  \frac{(n_i - np_i)^2}{n p_i} \frac{n_i}{n p_i} \phi\left(\frac{n_i-np_i}{n p_i}\right) \\
&= \sum_i \frac{(n_i - np_i)^2}{n p_i} \left( 2 + 2 \frac{n_i}{n p_i} \phi\left(\frac{n_i-np_i}{n p_i}\right) \right) .
\end{align}
by using that $\sum_i n_i = n = \sum_i np_i$. The law of large number ensures that for every $i$
$$ \frac{n_i}{np_i} \phi\left( \frac{n_i-np_i}{np_i}\right) \to \phi(0) = -1/2 $$
almost surely as $n\to\infty$. Since $(n_i - np_i)^2 / (np_i)$ is bounded for every $i$,
$$2\sum_i n_i \ln \frac{n_i}{n p_i} - \sum_i \frac{(n_i - np_i)^2}{n p_i} \to 0 $$
in distribution, and thus (because 0 is constant) in probability.

Answer (score 0):

NOT AND ANSWER, ONLY TOO WEAK INEQUALITIES AT THIS TIME

You should replace all $n_i$ by $X_i^{(n)}$ in your question, and your proof. I did not read the proof, but the answer is trivially yes.

Note that saying that a sequence $(\xi_n)$ is $O_P(1)$, means that the sequence of distributions of the $(\xi_n)$ is tight; and saying that a sequence $(\xi_n)$ is $o_P(1)$, means that the sequence $(\xi_n)$ goes to $0$ in probability.

The random variable $(X_1^{(n)},\ldots,X_k^{(n)})$ has the same distribution as the sum of $n$ i.i.d random variables with distribution $p_1\delta_{e_1}+\cdots+p_k\delta_{e_k}$, where $(e_1,\ldots,e_k)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Theorem of Karl Pearson ensures that the random variables
$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(X_i^{(n)}-np_i)^2}{np_i}$
converge in distribution to $\chi^2_{k-1}$ as $n \to +\infty$. Tightness of the the sequence of their distributions follows.

On the one hand, by convexity of the function $f : x \mapsto x\ln(x)$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^{(n)}\ln \frac{X_i^{(n)}}{np_i} 
= n \sum_{i=1}^k p_i f\Big(\frac{X_i^{(n)}}{np_i}\Big) 
\ge nf\Big(\sum_{i=1}^k p_i\frac{X_i^{(n)}}{np_i}\Big) = nf(1) = 0.$$
On the other hand, by concavity of the function $\ln$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^{(n)} \ln \frac{X_i^{(n)}}{np_i} 
&\le& \sum_{i=1}^k X_i^{(n)}\Big(\frac{X_i^{(n)}}{np_i}-1\Big) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^k \Big(\frac{(X_i^{(n)})^2}{np_i}-X_i^{(n)}\Big) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^k \Big(\frac{(X_i^{(n)})^2}{np_i}-2X_i^{(n)}+np_i\Big) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(X_i^{(n)}-np_i)^2}{np_i}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^{(n)} \ln \frac{X_i^{(n)}}{np_i}$ is also $O_P(1)$.

Comment: Could you add a link to a statement (or reference) of the convergence towards the $\chi^2_{k-1}$? It is interesting though not related to OP’s original question. 
Also, I cannot find what LHS converges in probability to 0.

Comment: You are right. I corrected my answer. Pearson theorem can be found in statistic books, since it is the theoretical foundation of the $\chi^2$ test. Yet, I did not find a reference on internet.

Comment: I like the double use of convexity to obtain inequalities that sandwich the quantity! But the bounds don’t match, do they? You get $0\leq \sum \dots \leq \sum \frac{(X_i^{(n)}-np_i)^2}{np_i} + O_P(1)$. – In the first one, why is the first occurence of $f$ outside of the sum? – In the second one, you forgot the $\ln$ in the first sum. – Second paragraph, the first sentence, "Note that saying that a sequence..." is unfinished.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that too quickly. I hope it is fine now. Pearson Theorem follows from central limit Theorem by the application of a suitable quadratic form.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typos. Your lower bound on $\sum_i X_i \ln \frac{X_i}{np_i}$ is still $0$ though, which is strictly weaker than OP’s. Do you think there is a way to improve your method to get the correct lower bound?